# Can't build selenium image in docker

Tags: java, selenium, docker

I am quite new to docker, and I am trying to get a really small selenium framework with just 1 test in the container. The test works all fine locally, but when I try to build it in the container it fails at the last stap when it tries to execute the tests via the mvn test command.

I get the following error: "could not start a new session. possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure".

[image: This is my dockerfile]

[image: dockerfile pt2]

And this is my test I'm trying to get in the container:

[image: Seleniumtest]

I quess it is because I'm not doing something right when it comes to the browser. Any feedback to get me a step further would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing my codes, How I manage docker and selenium. Hope it can help you

**First create selenium HUB**

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:3.141.0-actinium
```

**Then connect nodes with hub**

```
docker run -d -P -p 5900:5900 --link selenium-hub:hub -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.141.0-actinium
```

And Add the codes in      **@BeforeMethod**

```
 @BeforeMethod
    public void Openbrowser() throws MalformedURLException {
   nodeUrl =  "http://172.17.0.3:5555/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.getCurrent());
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
```

You will get more details about docker here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

Also using chrome nodes debug you can view browser using vnc viewer.

Hope it will help you.